# Multimedia interview preperation

Tags: gstreamer

I have hands-on experience in Multimedia framework on Symbian 
But I have knowledge of GStreamer and basic understanding of Multimedia protocols ( no in depth knowledge and no hands-on )

I have these two queries

1, Can I mention these facts about GStreamer and Multimedia protocols in resume and what kind of questions in these areas am I be hit upon ( for GSteramer, Multimedia protocols )

2, Can anyone refer any good books that talk about : GSteramer, Multimedia protocols ( like RTP, RTSP, etc., )

Answer (score 0):

Bit offtopic maybe ... Anyway, mention technologies in your CV your feel comfortable getting asked about. Otherwise clearly state the level of expertise. If you are getting the job and you don't know the stuff, you will feel unhappy or might get fired.

Recommendations for book is hard. Regarding GStreamer, the best advice is to use it. It takes time to learn a technology, always.